# non-RESTful operation using stored procedure

Tags: backbone.js

I have a number of complex stored procedures using queries containing many table joins, temp data, grouping, sorting etc. So I want to poke in query parameters and return the dataset back from my stored procedure.

If the server code is written in PHP and calls a MYSQL stored procedure, returning JSON, how can I best achieve this using Backbone.js hence the question:

Is it possible to perform non-RESTfull operations using Backbone.js and any code examples please?

Comment: Because you're most likely already using jQuery/Zepto, you can use `$.ajax`to make the service call. Just create a custom method on a Collection, Model, View, or any other class where the service call logically "belongs". Backbone doesn't provide any built-in support for non-RESTful non-CRUD operations, so you're left to your own devices on how to structure the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can still just point a Collection / Model to your URL, even if it isn't entirely RESTful.  When you call fetch on a Backbone Collection, you can pass in what will eventually be the $.ajax data param:

`MyCollection.fetch({data: {page: 3}});`

This should make it easier to still use Backbone objects but with the flexibility to work with whatever URL/param structure your PHP endpoints requires.